# How to wait a fadeout effect and then remove the element?

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a `<tr>` which will be removed when clicked in delete button, but before doing `.remove()` or `empty()` I'd like to wait for some `fadeOut()` effect.

```
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
setTimeout("$(this).closest('tr').remove()",1000);
```

is not working, it only fades out.

Comment: If you can live with having the element in the dom, but hidden from view: `$(this).closest('tr').hide('slow')`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) after `fadeOut()`

```
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

It fires the callback just after the `fadeOut()` operation is done, in this case after `400ms`.

Hope this helps, Sinan.